# Getting "Unsupported FBSDKGraphRequest attachment" when posting photo with tags

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've been trying to use the FBSDKGraphRequest to upload a photo with caption and tagged friends but I'm really struggling to make the tags work. Here's what I got:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"caption" : message,
                             @"picture" : UIImagePNGRepresentation(image),
                             @"tags"    : @[@{@"tag_uid": @902893713061742, @"x":@0.0, @"y":@0.0},
                                            @{@"tag_uid": @902486513129784, @"x":@10.0, @"y":@10.0}],
                             };

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:parameters tokenString:token.tokenString version:@"v2.3" HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    else
        NSLog(@"Success");
}];
[connection start];
```

But everytime I try to run it throws this error:

> FBSDKLog: Unsupported FBSDKGraphRequest attachment:(
>           {
>           "tag_uid" = 902893713061742;
>           x = 0;
>           y = 0;
>       },
>           {
>           "tag_uid" = 902486513129784;
>           x = 10;
>           y = 10;
>       }
>   ), skipping.

I already tried several different ways to attach the @"tags" info but none of them did the job. Does anyone know the right way to do this? Is this even possible? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/ made me think so.

EDIT: Tried posting without tags and then updating the post id with them but still no success :(

Answer (score 3):

You can't upload a photo with caption and tagged friends using same FBSDKGraphRequest. You have to call different methods for different task as shown in below:

For message like caption and tags:

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]){
 NSDictionary *params = @{
                        @"message": @"This is a test message",
                       };
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
         NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
        else{
            UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FBSDKGraphRequest" message:@"Text Shared successfully..!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [av show];
            }
 }];
}
```

For posting a photo:

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]){
NSDictionary *params = @{@"sourceImage":UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)};
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FBSDKGraphRequest" message:@"Image Shared successfully..!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [av show];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Graph API Error: %@", [error description]);
    }
  }];
}
```

Hope that can help you...:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this still doesn't solve my problem. I want to post a photo and also tag a few friends within the same post. Nevermind though, it seems like this simply doesn't work on the current version of Graph API. It just makes me a little sad that Instagram does exactly that and I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a photo with a caption, you just need to change the "caption" key to "message"

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("publish_actions") {
     let params: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["message": "Caption", "sourceImage" : UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)]
     FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/photos", parameters: params, HTTPMethod: "POST").startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            // Handle result
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic code to get you started:

```
if (![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
            [self alertWithMessage:@"Log into FB and request publish_actions" title:@"Upload Failed"];
            return;
        }
NSDictionary *params = @{@"source":UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"snoopy.png"])};

[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                [self alertWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Result: %@", result] title:@"Post Photo Success!"];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Graph API Error: %@", [error description]);
            }
        }];
```

This is guaranteed to work as I've tested it myself. Remember to check if the access token you have has publish_actions permission, as that might also affect wether you can or can not upload people's pictures.

Comment: but this method not share text along image.